# How to sum two dimensional arrays

Tags: ruby, matrix, multidimensional-array, sketchup

I have a two dimensional array = `[[12,34,35,21],[10,14,23,17],...]` infinity.

I would like to do this in ruby;

```
arr1 = [array[0][0]+array[1][0]+array[n+1][0]...,
array[0][1]+array[1][1]+array[n+1][1]...,
array[0][2]+array[1][2]+array[n+1][2]...,
array[0][3]+array[1][3]+array[n+1][3]...]
```

result (4x4)

```
arr1 = [[12+10+..],[34+14+..],[35+23..],[21+17+..]]
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does "infinity" mean?

Comment: it is not a 2x4 but it can be 16x4 or 24x4 ......infinity*4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose), and then sum each individual Array

```
array = [[12,34,35,21],[10,14,23,17]]

array.transpose.map {|a| a.inject(:+) }
# => [22, 48, 58, 38]
```

If you are using Ruby 2.4 or greater, you can use the [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) method

```
array.transpose.map(&:sum)
# => [22, 48, 58, 38]
```

For the output to be an Array or Arrays,

```
array.transpose.map {|a| [a.sum] }
# => [[22], [48], [58], [38]]
```

Comment: thank you Santhosh for the response, but my array is infinity, this works only if you have 2x4

Comment: This doesnt just work for 2x4, it works for a finite Array of arrays of same size.

Comment: Your array is NOT inifinite. You just can't store an infinite array in memory. The simple reason is that computer memory is limited and you can't store an infinite non-infinitesimal quantity in a finite space. http://av1611.com/kjbp/kjv-dictionary/infinite.html

Answer (score 1):

I have just written ruby code

```
h = Hash.new(0)
arr =  [[12, 34, 35, 21], [10, 14, 23, 17], [1, 2, 3]]  #Any size of nested array
arr.each do |a|
  a.each_with_index do |n,i|
    h[i]+=n
  end
end
h.values.map{|a| [a]}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Vector` from the standard library [matrix](https://github.com/ruby/matrix) gem.

```rb
require "matrix"

array_of_arrays = [
  [12, 34, 35, 21],
  [10, 14, 23, 17],
  # ...
]

vectors = array_of_arrays.map { |array| Vector[*array] }
summed_vector = vectors.inject { |memo, vector| memo + vector }

puts summed_vector # => Vector[22, 48, 58, 38]
```

You can substitute `Matrix` when your elements are multi-dimensional themselves.